# Logging POST data from $request_body

Tags: logging, nginx, http-post

I have my config setup to handle a bunch of GET requests which render pixels that work fine to handle analytics and parse query strings for logging. With an additional third party data stream, I need to handle a POST request to a given url that has JSON in an expected loggable format inside of it's request body. I don't want to use a secondary server with `proxy_pass` and just want to log the whole response into an associated log file like what it does with GET requests. A snippet of some code that I'm using looks like the following:

GET request (which works great):

```
location ^~ /rl.gif {
  set $rl_lcid $arg_lcid;
  if ($http_cookie ~* "lcid=(.*\S)")
  {
    set $rl_lcid $cookie_lcid;
  }
  empty_gif;
  log_format my_tracking '{ "guid" : "$rl_lcid", "data" : "$arg__rlcdnsegs" }';
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my.access.log my_tracking;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://my/url?id=$cookie_lcid? redirect;
}
```

Here is kinda what I am trying to do:
POST request (which does not work):

```
location /bk {
  log_format bk_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/bk.access.log bk_tracking;
}
```

Curling `curl http://myurl/bk -d name=example` gives me a 404 page not found.

Then I tried:

```
location /bk.gif {
  empty_gif;
  log_format bk_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/bk.access.log bk_tracking;
}
```

Curling `curl http://myurl/bk.gif -d name=example` gives me a `405 Not Allowed`.

My current version is `nginx/0.7.62`. Any help in the right direction is very much appreciated! Thanks!

***UPDATE***
So now my post looks like this:

```
location /bk {
  if ($request_method != POST) {
    return 405;
  }
  proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:$server_port/dummy;
  log_format my_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my.access.log my_tracking;
}
location /dummy { set $test 0; }
```

It is logging the post data correctly, but returns a 404 on the requesters end. If I change the above code to return a 200 like so:

```
location /bk {
  if ($request_method != POST) {
    return 405;
  }
  proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:$server_port/dummy;
  log_format my_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my.access.log my_tracking;
  return 200;
}
location /dummy { set $test 0; }
```

Then it return the `200` correctly, but no longer records the post data.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
Kinda found a working solution. Hopefully this can help other on their way.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I'm up against a similar problem.

Comment: Instead of doing the `set $test 0;` try doing `return 200;` from the dummy location, for me it then returns a 200 as expected and I get the body logged still.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This solution works like a charm:

```
http {

   log_format postdata $request_body;

   server {     
      location = /post.php {
         access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;
         fastcgi_pass php_cgi;
      }
   }
}
```

I think the trick is making nginx believe that you will call a CGI script.

Edit 2022-03-15: there is some discussion on where `log_format` should be set. The documentation clearly says that it needs to be in the `http` context: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

If you put `log_format` in the `server` context, nginx will fail to load the config: `nginx: [emerg] "log_format" directive is not allowed here in <path>:<line>` (tested with nginx 1.20 on ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: I have to move "log_format postdata $request_body;" to server part because nginx says "log_format directive is not allowed here"

Comment: This is the right answer. Except, like @OlegNeumyvakin mentioned, I had to move the `log_format` part. But in my case, I had to move it to inside the "http" block, instead of inside the "server" block, for it to work. But this did the trick!

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin & Matt : I have put your remarks into the answer itself (awaiting review currently). Thank you!

Comment: I even had to move the `log_format` line above the server part. But then it worked well. ( nginx/1.9.3 )

Comment: yes, log_format is only allowed in the http part of the nginx config. I changed the example accordingly.

Comment: Tested in nginx 1.20. The fastcgi is not required; it worked for me with proxy_pass in the location.

Answer (score 53):

Try echo_read_request_body.

"[echo_read_request_body](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule#echo_read_request_body) ... Explicitly reads request body so that the $request_body variable will always have non-empty values (unless the body is so big that it has been saved by Nginx to a local temporary file)."

```
location /log {
  log_format postdata $request_body;
  access_log /mnt/logs/nginx/my_tracking.access.log postdata;
  echo_read_request_body;
}
```

Comment: This worked better than the accepted answer, since it did not need fastcgi to be installed

Comment: install by `apt-get install nginx-full`

Comment: @user4I can see dash only in my logs. What's the problem? I use echo_read_request_body. and echo module installed

Comment: for me, if I redirect (eg 301/302), `request_body` disappears

Comment: @dcousens at what point are you serving the 301/302? If you're setting the 301/302 redirect right in the nginx location directive, then the behaviour you're seeing makes sense. If it's happening after some php processing, that would be a little odd.  You should start a new stack overflow question so someone can help you.

Comment: in the location directive.  I don't hesitate to announce that my experience with nginx is relatively low,  but it wasn't immediately clear to me why the `request_body` would disappear,  or why that would be sensical.

Comment: Work like a charm. Though echo module externally needs to be added in docker Nginx version by building dynamically. Follow this for building dynamically https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/ and also download module from here https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module/releases/tag/v0.62

Answer (score 20):

Ok. So finally I was able to log the post data and return a 200. It's kind of a hacky solution that I'm not too proud of which basically overrides the natural behavior for error_page, but my inexperience of nginx plus timelines lead me to this solution:

```
location /bk {
  if ($request_method != POST) {
    return 405;
  }
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:$server_port/success;
  log_format my_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my_tracking.access.log my_tracking;
}
location /success {
  return 200;
}
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
  root   /var/www/nginx-default;
  log_format my_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my_tracking.access.log my_tracking_2;
}
```

Now according to that config, it would seem that the proxy pass would return a 200 all the time. Occasionally I would get 500 but when I threw in an error_log to see what was going on, all of my request_body data was in there and I couldn't see a problem. So I caught that and wrote to the same log. Since nginx doesn't like the same name for the tracking variable, I just used my_tracking_2 and wrote to the same log as when it returns a 200. Definitely not the most elegant solution and I welcome any better solution. I've seen the post module, but in my scenario, I couldn't recompile from source.

Comment: The solution you came up with is very similar to the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609472/really-logging-the-post-request-body-instead-of-with-nginx Since nginx doesn't parse the body unless sending to a proxy or a fast-cgi server, proxying to itself works.

Comment: we use a similar solution, by proxy_pass the POST request to the another location.

Answer (score 20):

The solution below was the best format I found.

```
log_format postdata escape=json '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_body"';
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name api.some.com;

        location / {
         access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;
         proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

}
```

For this input

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://api.deprod.com/postEndpoint
```

Generate that great result

```
201.23.89.149 -  [22/Aug/2019:15:58:40 +0000] "POST /postEndpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 265 "" "curl/7.64.0" "{\"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Comment: Also, note that using `escape=none` will just output the JSON as it came, without having the quotes escaped (if that is desirable for your use case)

Comment: Not working. Is there anything special needs to be done. For e.g. some specific module needs to be added?

Comment: I tested in brand new nginx , if you wanna test, just create a raw docker image from https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx and try. Maybe your nginx have a different config

Comment: this log GET requests too. I'm trying to log only post

Comment: postdata log remains empty for me.

Comment: I was using return after logging instead of forwarding the request.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: You included the result! I know this should be a given, but I think it should be encouraged. :)

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, this config worked for me:

```
location = /logpush.html {
  if ($request_method = POST) {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/push.log push_requests;
    proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1/logsink;
    break;
  }   
  return 200 $scheme://$host/serviceup.html;
}   
#
location /logsink {
  return 200;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`nginx` log format taken from here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

no need to install anything extra

worked for me for `GET` and `POST` requests:

```
upstream my_upstream {
   server upstream_ip:upstream_port;
}

location / {
    log_format postdata '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_body"';
    access_log /path/to/nginx_access.log postdata;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
    }
}
```

just change `upstream_ip` and `upstream_port`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  GET requests worked and their (empty) request bodies got written to the the log file.  POST requests failed with a 404.  Experimenting a bit, I found that *all* POST requests were failing.  I found a [forum posting asking about POST requests](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,57107,57107) and the solution there worked for me.  That solution?  Add a `proxy_header` line right before the `proxy_pass` line, exactly like the one in the example below.

```
server {
    listen       192.168.0.1:45080;
    server_name  foo.example.org;

    access_log  /path/to/log/nginx/post_bodies.log post_bodies;
    location / {
      ### add the following proxy_header line to get POSTs to work
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass   http://10.1.2.3;
    }
}
```

(This is with nginx 1.2.1 for what it is worth.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is below exhibit:

```
location /bk {
  if ($request_method != POST) {
    return 405;
  }
  proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:$server_port/dummy;
  log_format my_tracking $request_body;
  access_log  /mnt/logs/nginx/my.access.log my_tracking;
  
}
location /dummy {
   access_log off; 
   return 200;
}
```