# How do I get Unicorn to show post parameters in the development log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, webserver, unicorn

I just started giving Unicorn a try (over Thin), and so far I do like the format of the output, except that it doesn't appear to show the post parameters for various requests.  I really like this functionality to help debug forms etc....

Unicorn:

```
20:26:14 web.1     | 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2012 20:26:14] "POST /basic_simulations HTTP/1.1" 422 24259 0.4838
```

What I want... (this is from webrick):

```
Started POST "/basic_simulations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-17 20:27:22 -0700
Processing by BasicSimulationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx", "basic_simulation"=>{"x1706"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit my answers"}
```

Is there some config option or something of the sort where I can turn this functionality on?  Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're using Foreman with a procfile, you can add this line to your Procfile:

```
 devlog: tail -f log/development.log
```

and it will put the development log to terminal window like webrick.

Comment: Thanks! Just saw this :)  Not entirely sure that it answers my question though... I am able to see the development log, but it just does not include the same amount of information as Webrick did.... See my example above - I can see that a post went through, but not the contents of the params hash.

Comment: this doesn't answer his question. He wants to see the Started POST etc... in his logs.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE:

Add this to your config/application.rb file:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

More info [here](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/unicorn)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your **config/environments/development.rb** file:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

More info [here](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/unicorn)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your site configuration:

```
log_format postdata $request_body;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;
```

More informations here: [Logging POST data from $request_body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body)

Comment: hmmm - I'm not quite sure where to put this?  I was hoping there would be an option in /config/unicorn.rb

Comment: in your nginx site config file under sites-available folder

Comment: What about without nginx?  I'm using webrick / thin in development, and production would be on Heroku