# Code Problems of "Logging POST data from $request_body"

Tags: nginx

I want do the same thing as [Logging POST data from $request_body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body) and thanks to this question, I could log post data successfully.
But the data I got from the $request_body is encode, such as " will encode into \x22. 
How can I get the original data from the $request_body?

Comment: I know this is old, but did you found any solution for that?