# Really logging the POST request body (instead of "-") with nginx

Tags: http, post, logging, nginx, webserver

I'm trying to log POST body, and add `$request_body` to the `log_format` in `http` clause, but the `access_log` command just prints "-" as the body after I send POST request using:

```
curl -d name=xxxx myip/my_location
```

My log_format (in `http` clause):

```
log_format client '$remote_addr - $remote_user $request_time $upstream_response_time '
                  '[$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent $request_body "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

My location definition(in server clause):

```
location = /c.gif {  
  empty_gif;  
  access_log logs/uaa_access.log client;  
}
```

How can I print the actual POST data from curl?

Comment: Sounds like these guys found a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Nginx doesn't parse the client request body unless it really needs to, so it usually does not fill the `$request_body` variable.

The exceptions are when:

- it sends the request to a proxy,
- or a fastcgi server.

So you really need to either add the `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi_pass` directives to your block.

The easiest way is to send it to Nginx itself as a proxied server, for example with this configuration:

```
location = /c.gif {  
    access_log logs/uaa_access.log client;
    # add the proper port or IP address if Nginx is not on 127.0.0.1:80
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/post_gif; 
}
location = /post_gif {
    # turn off logging here to avoid double logging
    access_log off;
    empty_gif;  
}
```

If you only expect to receive some key-pair values, it might be a good idea to limit the request body size:

```
client_max_body_size 1k;
client_body_buffer_size 1k;
client_body_in_single_buffer on;
```

I also received "405 Not Allowed" errors when testing using `empty_gif;` and curl (it was ok from the browser), I switched it to `return 200;` to properly test with curl.

Comment: I tried using the same, but in my nginx logs I still find request_body to be empty .

Comment: I want to log the "response content" which is a json, to the nginx log. example: http://<some_ip>/prod/get_sources gives me JSON containing list of sources. How can I log this into the nginx log.

Comment: No, this method can't be used to log the output of your application, just the input it receives, like a REST request using PUT/POST as json values, even form encoded strings.

You may forward data from your application to nginx using error log, though.

Comment: sorry but I am new to this, can you tell me more about how can I forward the data to nginx.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still facing this problem, check your `client_body_buffer_size` value.

If the req body size is bigger than `client_body_buffer_size` then nginx will replace it with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I had fun making this work - I simply wanted a way to catch and log SSL posts for a special testing situation. Anyhow, here's how I did it.

Of course the log format needs $request_body somewhere.

In the http (non SSL) portion of the config, I forward to myself - to force the logging. Use whatever paths are good for your purposes.

```
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/kluge; 

    }
    location /kluge {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        access_log off; 

    }
```

And in the SSL part (which is where I was doing my testing primarily), the same, but forwarding to the http server:

```
  location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        # following required to get things to log... 
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/kluge; 
    }
```

Works nicely and minimally invasive to the config. Of course I could make it less invasive by not using '/' path but some path unique to my testing requirements.

Thanks to previous posts! I learned a lot about nginx thru this.