# Logging/processing css-formatted jQuery-posted div data?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to log a javascript-calculated result div from an anonymous little survey produced via a Wordpress plugin.

The html produced is:

```
<div ref="fieldname57_1" class="cff-summary-item">
<span class="summary-field-title cff-summary-title">Yearly costs</span>       
<span class="summary-field-value cff-summary-value">£120</span></div> 
(...)
```

It is rendered as

```
Yearly costs: £120
Monthly costs: 10
```

because the css has, for example:

```
fbuilder .cff-summary-title:after {
    content: ': ';
}
```

I can grab and post the text and [log it with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17765232/401713) with a basic jquery post handler like this:

```
var stuff = jQuery('#fieldname66_1').text();
jQuery.post( "/formpost.txt", { name: "result", value: stuff } );
```

but everything comes out as `Yearly costs£120Monthly costs£10`

I can grab `jQuery('#fieldname66_1').html()` but then I have the html to process.

I could do back-end processing - I'm a node-newbie but have it installed and I can see various npm packages which MIGHT be co-erced in processing the output.

I'm aware of jQuery's makeArray and toArray functions, but these still give me the html.
I could use .next() to traverse my way through the spans and get the results into an array.

But ... **am I missing a trick here?**

- When I say "log", it doesn't need to be "per line" log format -
- I'd still to log the entire div "as rendered". I can't change the plugin
  code, even if I could let's treat this as a learning tool!
- The entire page output is javascript, rendered in-browser.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First off, that is terrible HTML. A table or a definition list would be better. And if you want to post that data to a server, best would be to have a form with fields.

If you want to keep it as it is, get the text of the spans separately and and join them together with a colon yourself.

Are the multiple title/value pairs in one item? If yes, what do you want to have between two title/value pairs when sending them to the server?

Comment: Thanks! Can't do anything about the html - yes, in an ideal world it wouldn't be like that. Looking at it again, I think the easiest way is to write a php handler that will just create an html wrapper with the relevant line of CSS, and then just display the data as a mini webpage. Horrible, I know, but small amount of data and low volume of responses make that probably the most time-cost-effective method. Still open to alternatives though!