# Sending server and client side web application logs to centralized ELK stack

Tags: java, reactjs, nginx, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a single page web application based on a react/redux stack as the frontend and Java (Jetty) server as the backend. 
All server side logs are written to files and filebeat transfers them to a centralized ELK.

What is the best practice method for sending client (browser) logs to the same centralized ELK?

-------------- **EDIT** --------------

One possibility is to create a new entry in Nginx which will write the logs and access it from the client. How can I config Nginx to such functionality? (links in comments)

Comment: [logging-post-data in nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body)

Comment: [logging-post-data in nginx 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609472/really-logging-the-post-request-body-instead-of-with-nginx)

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by "client-side logs". All requests made by a client will hit the Nginx server and the logs are stored there.

Comment: I meant what are the best practices for saving web application logs to centralized ELK. It required for the production environment.

Comment: Personally, I find filebeat to work fine. Might try syslog from Nginx into logstash, if that's a thing

Comment: @cricket_007 he means precisely what he said: logging done on the client-side, in his JavaScript code, for instance through `console.log` calls. The OP wants a design that will let him capture such logs and push them into his ELK stack.

Comment: @Mark Fine. Then I would suggest  use the Elasticsearch REST API rather than `console.log`