# How can I read and manipulate POST request variables with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx (v1.4.1) to proxy an external service, but would like to be able to inspect and possibly modify the body of a `POST` request before proxying it. The problem is, I'm currently unable to access the `POST` request body while handling the request, whether through the `$request_body` variable or otherwise.

I've read a number of posts and SO questions, and have implemented [this suggested strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939382/logging-post-data-from-request-body), which is intended to allow the logging of the `POST` body (when using a `proxy_pass` directive). However, while this works for me I'm still unable to read anything from `$request_body` during the processing of the request.

For clarity, here's the relevant section of my configuration:

```
location /proxy-this/ {
    client_max_body_size 8k;
    client_body_buffer_size 16k;
    client_body_in_single_buffer on;
    proxy_pass https://example.com/external-endpoint/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length '';
}
```

And what I'd like to be able to do:

```
location /proxy-this/ {
    ... (same configuration as above) ...
    set $request_body $request_body&extra_param=1;
}
```

I'm aware that this is possible using the `nginx_lua` module, and have looked at the `HttpFormInputModule`, but the first seems overkill and the latter hasn't been updated in a while.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using [proxy_set_body](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_body)?

That would be like

```
location /proxy-this/ {
  ... (same configuration as above) ...
  proxy_set_body $request_body&extra_param=1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Trying to modify the POST data doesn't sound sensible. I suggest setting the extra param in the query string when you proxy_pass it and then read it as a GET variable.

```
proxy_pass https://example.com/external-endpoint/?extra_param=1;
```

Comment: It might not be sensible, but it's what I'm trying to do :). I don't have control over the service I'm `proxy_pass`ing to, so this isn't an option. Sorry!

Comment: I came across this in google and this is useless, trying to add an API secret/client by proxy i.e. editing the post body is a very valid and very sensible requirement.